# How to use Injector Function on Ionic Creator?can I create a loggin app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a login authentication for app in ionic creator. This function Stops me from Sending it to the page. It keeps on giving error

[image: Screenshot of that error]

///this code of my login page controller

```
 function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $location, AuthenticationService) {
        // reset login status
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();

        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.dataLoading = true;
            AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
                if(response.success) {
                    AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                    $state.go('tabsController.results', params);
                    $location.path('/');
                } else {
                    $scope.error = response.message;
                    $scope.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

///and here goes my code for service

```
.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {



            $http.post('/api/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
               .success(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
               });

        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; 
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
        };

        return service;
    }])
```

every time i try to run the program my Browser show error...
I would be happy to be helped...
thakyou

Comment: Can you share some of your code or provide some more context?

Comment: thank you ....wait m figuring out how can i send code to you

Comment: what you mean by `  $location.path('/');` can you please  remove it and try..?

Comment: still not working....thank you